# How to get Sum of Knowledge Article Thumbs Up and Down Votes based on Role / Profile

Tags: reporting, knowledge, articles, lightning-knowledge

Please help with the below problem:

Currently using Report on Article Vote Statistics we can get the sum of the count of thumbs up and down channel wise (Internal App, Customer etc).
Is there any other way to get the total thumbs up and down votes user role/profile wise.

Example:
[image]

Thanks,
Bhavik

Answer (score 2):

> You can not categorize knowledge articles on the basis of profiles as
>   [KnowledgeArticleVoteStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm) only stores `channel` and `normalized score` for an `article`.

However, You can use the [Knowledge Base Dashboards & Reports](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HXO9EAO) app exchange product by salesforce labs to monitor your knowledge base.

Comment: Ok, Will my requirement be achieved using the "Knowledge Base Dashboards & Reports app exchange product". I have already installed that product. Can you tell me which report / dashboard will get me that data.